# 'Update Model from Database' changes the name of the EntityContainer to 'Entities'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework, model first.  Over time, I noticed that several database models would no longer be generated properly -- in the class, the model name would be changed to 'Entities', like this:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext {
   public Entities(): base("name=Entities") { }
...
```

Obviously, my code would no longer compile until I edited the Context.cs file, changing the three instances of 'Entities' back to the correct value.  Over time this started happening with several databases, and became very irksome.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I discovered a solution.  Instead of editing the Context.cs file, I edited the .edmx file.

1. First open the .edmx file using "Open with..." and select 'XML Editor'. This will open the .edmx file as text, instead of showing the usual database diagram. (If you already have the diagram open, you may have to close it before doing "Open with...")
2. Search the .edmx file for "Entities".  I got two hits, shown below:

```html
<EntityContainer Name="Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
<EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="iVgContribsModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="Entities">
```

3. Replace the word "Entities" with the name you want to use for the database.

If you get too many hits in step 2, you might try including double quotes around the word "Entities".

Once I do this, the name seems to persist across multiple "Update Model from Database" operations. I don't understand what caused the problem, nor why the solution works, but so far it works for me.

Comment: That happened because when you created for first time your model, you named the container "Entities", then when your class is updated the container is renamed with the data on the .edx file created for the first time. You can change that property without messing with the edx files, just go to the designer, click on some area where there is no entity to bring up the properties of the model and change "Entity container name"

Comment: Thank you so much Gusman! That is a much easier way of doing it.  I never heard of an EntityContainer before.  I guess I should pay closer attention.